# Two questions that need to be closed as a duplicates

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I’ve noticed that [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14195/en-passant-usage-after-one-or-more-moves) question, which is about if an en passant capture can be delayed, and [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/why-can-i-not-make-an-en-passant-capture) question, which is about if an en passant capture can be done on the seventh rank, are both answered by [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/two-questions-about-how-the-en-passant-capture-works) much older question.

The two younger questions need to be closed as duplicates of the older one. Since they are old questions, I felt that the review queue simply wouldn’t be adequate for these  so I am pointing it out here. Please post an answer when they are closed so it can be accepted and this question’s business is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I felt that the review queue simply wouldn’t be adequate for these so I am pointing it out here.

I'm curious as to why. The Close Votes review queue is pretty fast and reliable for a site the size of Chess Stack Exchange; if you expect other users (reviewers, but also people visiting the question and let's not forget the author) not to see why it's a duplicate, you can always edit the auto-generated "Does this answer your question?" to include some additional information.

I can probably hammer the question, but I'd prefer if you do this the regular way.

Comment: Well I have voted to close them before but to no avail, hence why I brought it up on Meta to bring attention to the matter. I have now done it the normal way as you requested.

Comment: There's no indication of a prior close votes review: https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/14195/timeline

Comment: Hm, probably just a false memory then. Sorry for any confusion.